# Spell check for Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, spell-check

Are there any spell-check plugins available for Internet Explorer?

I know that Chrome and Firefox have this built-in, but I wondered if anything similar was available for IE?

(Specifically I'm looking for the "red wavy underline" spellcheck-as-you-type feature.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IE7Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/) adds many functions to IE6/7/above, including a spell checker. Documentation for this feature is [here](http://wiki.ie7pro.com/index.php/Spell_Check_Dictionary).

Comment: Wow, this looks like several firefox addons rolled together!

Comment: I don't know if that's a good idea or not (though).

Comment: and if you're looking for more IE 'add ons', have a look at Bayden's IEToys (no spellchecker though but useful stuff nonetheless). and while you're there, check their product portfolio, Bayden Systems offers a variety of other great utilities (e.g. SlickRun, SetRes, ConsoleCapture to name but a few) http://www.bayden.com/ietoys/

Comment: Thanks, IE7Pro did what I wanted. I was able to disable the features I didn't need, and also was able to download an English (UK) spelling dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

[ieSpell](http://www.iespell.com/) -- but its last update seems to be in 2006!
But, [ieSpell 2.5.1 build 106](http://download.cnet.com/ieSpell/3000-12512_4-10208550.html), shows over 10K downloads in the last week.

Comment: It's not as-you-type.

Answer (score 2):

TinySpell has come in handy a number of times,
and it's very easy to use.

http://www.tinyspell.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll find the "as you type" for IE, but in addition to the previously mentioned [ieSpell](http://www.iespell.com/), the [Google Toolbar](http://toolbar.google.com) also has a spell checker.

Comment: I tried the Google toolbar, but didn't stick with it due to the lack of as-you-type spellchecking.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an interesting blog article on it, including a few plugin suggestions http://www.inspiredbytechnology.com/index.php/2011/01/14/will-internet-explorer-ever-have-a-spell-checker/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid (and downvoted) if the linked page changes. **The link is invalid now, so please act.** See [How To Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer) for why it is important.